# multiprocessing stuck showing No such file or directory '/dev/null'

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, multiprocessing, dev-null

I'm writing some code using multiprocessing in python, and running in docker debian stretch image, there are multiple containers running at the same time but only one is running these piece of code.

The node of running this piece of code stuck for a long time in log and I started look at the logs of the container. The log flushes the error of the same thing.

```
Process Poolworker-24227: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 259, in _bootstrap sys.stdin = open(os.devnull) 
I0Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/null' 

Process Poolworker-24228: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 259, in _bootstrap sys.stdin = open(os.devnull) 
I0Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/null' 

Process PoolWorker-24229: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 259, in _bootstrap sys.stdin = open(os.devnull) 
I0Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/null'
```

This not happens all the time, next time I tried the same func, somehow this works.Would think something related to lock.
And for certain /dev/null is actually there in container.

The piece of code is quite straightforward that use pool.map()

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = pool.map(func_with_logging, some_list_of_param)
```

Comment: Does `/dev/null` actually exist on your filesystem? What's the output when you do `ls -l /dev/null` in command line?

Comment: Yes the file exists and I can write text into it, and use ls shows normal permission of rw for root user.( I use root as default in container)